Make pydantic v2 ignores class fields
I'd like to make pydantic (v2) to ignore some class fields. By saying "ignore" I mean I hope pydantic will not process these fields in validation, serialization, __eq__, __repr__...
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, PrivateAttr


class A(BaseModel):
    f1: int = Field()
    f2: int = PrivateAttr()
    _pf3: int

None of three methods above is what I want, pydantic will recognize f1, f2 and _pf3 in different ways and record them into its private structure.
For example, pydantic will record _pf3 into its __pydantic_private__ and use it in __eq__ comparing. So test below won't pass every time:
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator


class A(BaseModel):
    f: int
    _pf: int | None = None

    @model_validator(mode="after")
    def after(self):
        self._pf = random.choice(list(range(10000)))

def test_a():
    a = A(f=1)
    b = A(f=1)
    assert a == b # <-- will fail due to a._pf != b._pf

I do find out a way to achieve this: provide these fields as @property or @cached_property. According to documentation, pydantic will ignore them if not decorated with the @computed_field which provided by pydantic.
Is there any way that I can still write these fields like normal class fields while making pydantic ignores them?

By convention in Pydantic _f2: int = PrivateAttr() and _f2: int are the same thing. Fields starting with an underscore are considered private by default, see https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#private-model-attributes.
EDIT:
The example at the bottom is incorrect, because private attributes are not set on init and thus are ignored. This is documented behavior: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#private-model-attributes.
OUTDATED:
Otherwise it seems a private attribute is exactly what you want. See the following example:
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, PrivateAttr


class A(BaseModel):
    f1: int = Field()
    _f2: int = PrivateAttr()
    
a = A(f1=1, _f2=2)

# rep does not include _f2
print(repr(a))

# dump does not include _f2
data = a.model_dump()
print(data)

# does not raise error
A(f1=1, _f2="three")

# passes even if _f2 is different
assert a == A(f1=1, _f2=4)

Which prints:
A(f1=1)
{'f1': 1}

I hope this helps!

Thanks for your kindly reply but... that's not what I want, plz check the test code in updated question. I found it's hard to find some style like = Field() or = PrivateAttr() to make pydantic ignore the field. Maybe pydantic doesn't meant to work like what I want, I don't know.

Indeed I can confirm that your example fails. However the example I gave in my answer works. This looks like a bug in Pydantic to me. I decided to open an issue: https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/9192 This should also clarify the intended behavior.

Yeah, my initial question is "how to make pydantic ignore some fields in __eq__ and avoid override nice pydantic __eq__ function". But I'd prefer a way to make pydantic completely ignore a field... since I'm not sure where the __pydantic_private__ inner field is used. Anyway, thanks for the issue! It can solve my current question.
